# css div fit image child in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, width, inheritance

I try to have a div that fit it width from image child. It works in google chrome, safari but not in =< IE9 and some other browsers...This div is responsive and the height is in % defined by js.

Here the html code :

```
<div class="element wide music">
    <div class="element-container element-back-bg5">

        <div class="audio-player-cover">
            <img class="cover" src="http://www.konbini.com/fr/files/2013/04/Random-Access-Memories-Daft-Punk-88883716862.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="audio-player-informations">
            <div class="element-audio-separator"></div>
            <div class="audio-player-songtitle">Get Lucky feat Colin Farrell</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the css :

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    height: 180px;
    border: none;
}
.element-container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 2px!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.audio-player-cover div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
.audio-player-informations {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
.audio-player-cover img.cover {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
.audio-player-artiste {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1; 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family: 'MavenProLight-300';
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
/* Title */
.audio-player-songtitle {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1; 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family: 'MavenProLight-300';
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.element-back-bg5 {
    background:#ECEDF0;
    color: #58585C;
}
.element-audio-separator {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.element.wide  .audio-player-songtitle, .element.square .audio-player-artiste {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

And the fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/zKEkG/1/

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry but your css is very messy. It looks like you're lacking a good understanding of the box model and how positioning works. I recommend you read:

More about box model:
http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/box-model

More about how to use positioning properly using css:
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

As for a quick fix to your problem, if you set the height of the cover image directly to the height of the container, it should work cross browser.

```
.audio-player-cover img.cover {
    /*Manually set height to match container*/ height: 180px;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Edited: 

Misinterpreted question. Seems like the issue is stricter css selector. 

Changed: audio-play-cover to div.audio-player-cover 

jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/zKEkG/8

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's no working... Did you try it in a fiddle on IE9 for example? In chrome the behavior is correct like this http://jsfiddle.net/zKEkG/1/ . But In IE the height can't be set to 100% in RESPONSIVE context (that mean I can't fixed a height in px)...

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong. Look like you just didn't do your css selector properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/zKEkG/8/
Changed: audio-play-cover to div.audio-player-cover